# How can I execute an update (named query) in Hibernate Template?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a namedQuery like this:

```
@NamedQueries ({ ...

@NamedQuery(name = "myUpdate", query = "update User set country = 'EN' where user.id = :id")
```

...
})

In dao layer

```
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(...?)
```

**UPDATE**

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.getNamedQuery("myUpdate");
getHibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate(query.getQueryString(), id);
```

I get an error:

Hibernate: update User, set country=EN where id = 2343 ORA-00971: missing SET keyword

Anybody now how can resolve this problem?

**UPDATE 2**

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myUpdate", query =
 "update User set country = 'EN' where
 user.profile.id = ?")
```

OK

```
  @NamedQuery(name = "myUpdate", query =
     "update User set country = 'EN' where
     user.profile.name = ?")
```

NOT OK :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that feature is missing in spring, as the named queries are supposed to be used only to retrieve data. One thing you can do is (this is a bit of a work around)

```
Session session = getHibernateTemplate().getSession();
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("myUpdate");
String update = query.getQueryString();
getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate(update, [params]);
```

I would put that in some kind of helper, so your DAO logic doesn't have to go around spring too.

#### edit

there's a dangling comma between User and set "update User **,** set country=EN where"

Comment: It's works. Thanks! But unfortually I have another problem. See UPDATE

Comment: That is ridiculous. I do not have a comma there. The query is exactly the same as the Stack. :(

Comment: if hibernate is adding that, then it's very odd. Can you get the result of `query.getQueryString()`?. And if that's correct, try the query `update User set country = 'EN' where id = :id`

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a very old question but I had the same problem today. I realized that the update does not work since you cannont have a join inside of a simple UPDATE. That is also the reason why the comma is added. Hibernate tries to rewrite the query like this:

```
UPDATE User u, Profile p SET u.country = 'EN' where p.name = ? AND p.id = u.profile.id
```

To solve the issue you need to select the ids from the second table yourself.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "myUpdate", query = ""
  + " UPDATE User u "
  + " SET country = 'EN' "
  + " WHERE u.profile.id IN ( "
  + "   SELECT p.id "
  + "   FROM Profile p "
  + "   WHERE p.name = ? "
  + " )"
```